# generating pink noise images in C with fftw

Tags: c, fftw

I'm trying to generate a 2d pink noise (1/f) image in C using FFTW

```
    fftw_complex * Xf = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nrows*ncolumns);
    fftw_plan ift = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(nrows,ncolumns,Xf,image,FFTW_BACKWARD|FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    for (int rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++) {
        for (int cc=0; cc<ncolumns; cc++) {
            if (rr<=nrows/2) {
                u = 1.0*rr/nrows;
            }
            else {
                u = 1.0*(rr-nrows)/nrows;
            }
            if (cc<=ncolumns/2) {
                v = 1.0*cc/ncolumns;
            }
            else {
                v = 1.0*(cc-ncolumns)/ncolumns;
            }
            // 1/f power spectrum
            w = pow(u,2)+pow(v,2);
            if (w!=0) {
                Sf = pow(w,-1/2);
            }
            else {
                Sf = 0;
            }
            // random phase
            phi = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
            // complex spectrum
            Xf[rr+nrows*cc][0] = sqrt(Sf) * cos(2*pi*phi);
            Xf[rr+nrows*cc][1] = sqrt(Sf) * sin(2*pi*phi);
        }
    }
    fftw_execute(ift);
```

When I do the inverse fourier transform in matlab using the same spectrum (real(ifft2(...)), I get a typical pink noise image (left below). But the image that is returned by FFTW is not pink noise (right): [example of pink noise images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPzBE.jpg).
If I try to make brown noise (1/f2), I get something even worse: [example and brown noise images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKNIq.jpg).
Would anyone have any idea why I don't get the proper image from FFTW inverse fourier transform? The images I get in matlab are correct so the spectrum doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex array `Xf` is too large for a c2r transform. The r2c transform of a real array of size `n0*n1` is a complex array of size `n0*(n1/2+1)` (see fftw [Real-data DFT Array Format](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format.html#Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format). It makes sense due to a particular property of the [DFT transform](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029). Indeed, if `X` is a real array of length `n`, the conponant `Xf[n-k]` of its DFT transform Xf is the complex conjugate of `Xf[k]`. As a result, time and memory can be saved by dropping half of the complex array.

By calling `fftw_plan ift = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(nrows,ncolumns,Xf,image,FFTW_BACKWARD|FFTW_ESTIMATE);` fftw creates a plan to transform back a `nrows*(ncolumns/2+1)` complex array `Xf` into a `nrow*ncolumn` array of reals. As a result, the frequencies are to be computed accordingly.

The following sample code based on yours produces VTK images which can be computed with paraview. It is compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3 -lm -Wall`

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<fftw3.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

int main(void){

    int nrows=400;
    int ncolumns=1000;

    double* image=malloc(nrows*ncolumns*sizeof(double));

    fftw_complex * Xf = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nrows*(ncolumns/2+1));
    fftw_plan ift = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(nrows,ncolumns,Xf,image,FFTW_BACKWARD|FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    int rr;  
    int cc;
    double u,v,w,phi,Sf; 

    for (rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++) {
        for (cc=0; cc<ncolumns/2+1; cc++) {
            if (rr<=nrows/2) {
                u = 1.0*rr/nrows;
            }

            else {
                u = 1.0*(rr-nrows)/nrows;
            }

            v = 1.0*cc/ncolumns;


            // 1/f power spectrum
            w = pow(u,2)+pow(v,2);
            if (w!=0) {
                // Sf = pow(w,-1./2);
                Sf = pow(w,-1.);
            }
            else {
                Sf = 0;
            }
            // random phase
            phi = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
            // complex spectrum
            //Xf[rr*(ncolumns/2+1)+cc][0] = sqrt(Sf) * cos(2*pi*phi);
            //Xf[rr*(ncolumns/2+1)+cc][1] = sqrt(Sf) * sin(2*pi*phi);
            Xf[rr*(ncolumns/2+1)+cc]=sqrt(Sf)*(cos(2*PI*phi)+I*sin(2*PI*phi));
        }
    }
    fftw_execute(ift);

    // writing to VTK file

    FILE* file=fopen("image.vtk","w");
    fprintf(file,"# vtk DataFile Version 2.0\n");
    fprintf(file,"pinknoise\n");
    fprintf(file,"ASCII\n");
    fprintf(file,"DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS\n");
    fprintf(file,"DIMENSIONS %d %d 1\n",nrows,ncolumns);
    fprintf(file,"ASPECT_RATIO 1 1 1\n");
    fprintf(file,"ORIGIN 0 0 0\n");
    fprintf(file,"POINT_DATA %d\n",nrows*ncolumns);
    fprintf(file,"SCALARS image double 1\n");
    fprintf(file,"LOOKUP_TABLE default\n");
    for (cc=0; cc<ncolumns; cc++) {
        for (rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++) {

            fprintf(file,"%lf ",image[rr*(ncolumns)+cc]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    fftw_destroy_plan(ift);
    fftw_free(Xf);
    free(image);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work. I misunderstood the FFTW documentation. Thanks,